# Train multiple tensorflow NN together

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a model the uses several different collections of features. There is one NN for each set of features but they all have the same structure. The NNs are built like the following,

```
results = []
sources = [input1, input2,...]
for src in sources :
    result = Dense(25)(src)
    results.append(result)
Model = model(input=sources, output=results)
```

I do have the model working such that it will compile and train.

My question is, since each component is separate, will the individual dense layers train using the loss from their corresponding y array? Or are all of the NNs trained using the combined loss?

I am hoping to keep all the NNs together like this if possible as they will always be run together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the variables in each different NN will be independent of one another and therefore the combined loss can be seen as independent. What you will have to be careful of is that you will have N output tensors, where N is the number of different neural networks you have (i.e. the length of the results array).

You will have to make sure that your labels are in the same structure as the output of the model manually or create a custom loss function to handle this. One way to do this is to merge the outputs using tf.stack or tf.concat and then duplicate the labels to match these.

Comment: My current version uses concat for the results array and returns that. It sounds like I should be okay, thanks.